# Uboot SERDES configuration for PCIEx4

Tags: u-boot, pci-e

I am trying to create a pcie x4 interface using a standard SERDES map on a Marvell 38x chip in Uboot. However lane verification prevents me from enabling the pcie x4 configuration.

The closest example I can find is this slm1363 board from this file: https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/3d4825446e4258192e1f2302d691a8c0c82a0975/arch/arm/mach-mvebu/serdes/a38x/high_speed_topology_spec-38x.c :

```
struct serdes_map db_config_slm1363_d[MAX_SERDES_LANES] = {
    {PEX0, SERDES_SPEED_5_GBPS, PEX_ROOT_COMPLEX_X4, 0, 0},
    {PEX1, SERDES_SPEED_5_GBPS, PEX_ROOT_COMPLEX_X4, 0, 0},
    {PEX2, SERDES_SPEED_5_GBPS, PEX_ROOT_COMPLEX_X4, 0, 0},
    {PEX3, SERDES_SPEED_5_GBPS, PEX_ROOT_COMPLEX_X4, 0, 0},
    {USB3_HOST0, SERDES_SPEED_5_GBPS, SERDES_DEFAULT_MODE, 0, 0},
    {USB3_HOST1, SERDES_SPEED_5_GBPS, SERDES_DEFAULT_MODE, 0, 0}
}
```

However that board was patched out in this commit https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/commit/544acb07ecebc096c9449e675481ba280311fb0b due to it being an unsupported topology?

If I configure uboot using the example above, I get the following on boot:

```
board SerDes lanes topology details:
 | Lane #  | Speed |  Type       |
 --------------------------------
 |   0    |  5   |  PCIe0       |
 |   1    |  5   |  PCIe1       |
 |   2    |  5   |  PCIe2       |
 |   3    |  5   |  PCIe3       |
 |   4    |  5   |  USB3 HOST0  |
 |   5    |  5   |  USB3 HOST1  |
 --------------------------------
hws_serdes_topology_verify: Warning: serdes lane 2 is set to type PCIe2.
hws_serdes_topology_verify: Maximum supported lanes are already set to this type (limit = 4)
hws_update_serdes_phy_selectors: SerDes lane #2 is  disabled
hws_serdes_topology_verify: Warning: serdes lane 3 is set to type PCIe3.
hws_serdes_topology_verify: Maximum supported lanes are already set to this type (limit = 4)
hws_update_serdes_phy_selectors: SerDes lane #3 is  disabled
board SerDes lanes topology details:
 | Lane #  | Speed |  Type       |
 --------------------------------
 |   0    |  5   |  PCIe0       |
 |   1    |  5   |  PCIe1       |
 |   4    |  5   |  USB3 HOST0  |
 |   5    |  5   |  USB3 HOST1  |
 --------------------------------
```

If i comment out the SERDES lane verification, it seems I can configure the x4 link successfully and recognize the drive that is attached. Can anyone shed some light on the proper way to configure this?

Thanks!
Tyler

Comment: It suggest that you use 'scripts/get_maintainer.pl drivers/pci' to find the people who could help and send a mail to them and the U-Boot mailing list.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the pro-tip.